# Cocoapods frameworks not installing properly

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, cocoapods

I can't seem to understand what is going on with my project and cocoapods, Xcode cannot find the frameworks except Firebase which is why I am confused. I'm getting the error `Project ' file not found`.  Xcode also gives me the error, `In file included from <built-in>:342:` I have tried to clean and build, emptying Xcode's cache and reinstalling Xcode. Can anyone please explain this thanks. 
Here's my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Soar_iPad' do
# Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for Soar_iPad
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'ExpandingMenu', '~> 0.1'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

[image]

Comment: do you access the project via the workspace file? did cocoapods downloaded the frameworks correctly?

Comment: Yes I opened the workspace file cocoa pods created; I believe cocoa pods installed the frameworks correctly, everything looked fine in terminal

Comment: Sometimes this happened to me I only have one solution when this happens: delete de Pod and start again. Regards.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but I still get the same error...

Comment: Have you tried putting `use_frameworks!` before the `target 'Soar_iPad' do` line? Also, are you opening the workspace file after you install the CocoaPods?

Comment: Yeah I just tried that but I got the same result

Comment: @Hightower98 I put a bounty on it so you can get going. Make sure you mark the answer that works.

Comment: @Adrian Ok thanks you very much!

Comment: Can you post the path from you home directory to you project folder? That might make it easier to figure out.

Comment: @Bawpotter my file path is `/Users/brandonhightower/Desktop/Project\ \"Nuova\ Vita\"/Soar-App1`

Comment: That's the directory to your .xcworkspace?

Comment: Yes my .xcworkspace is in that directory

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of that directory and post it?

Comment: @Bawpotter I added a screenshot of my directory in the original post

Comment: Okay. Search Finder for SwiftyJSON and/or pop. What comes up?

Comment: SwiftJSON shows up in my Pods directory I wrote an old podfile I have updated it, but the problem is still the same. My apologies...

Comment: Just to clarify- What are the Pods that you're missing right now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120131/discussion-between-bawpotter-and-hightower98).

Comment: Can you upload porject/sample project with the same issue?

Comment: @MCMatan I uploaded my project to github so you can have a look here is the link: https://github.com/BHigh17/soar-app

Comment: @Hightower98 getting 404..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong and why Xcode could not find the pod files. It was because my directory had double quotation marks in it, for example I had `/username/Desktop/Project "MyApp"/Project` and Xcode could not find my pod files. But for some reason I found that using single quotes worked so for example `/username/Desktop/Project 'MyApp'/Project`. It's weird but glad a solution was found. Thanks to everyone that helped!

Comment: Nicely done figuring this out on your own. I suspect you learned a considerable amount along the way.

Comment: Yes I did and thanks for your help in starting a bounty to bring more attention to this question!

Comment: Your directory where? In the podfile?

Comment: My root directory where my project and podfile are located @c0d3Junk13

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete workspace (.xcworkspace)
2. Delete Podfile.lock and Pods/ directory
3. Make sure your project builds
4. Upgrade cocoapods `gem install cocoapods` (optional)
5. Close project and run `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

1. `pod deintegrate`
2. `pod install`

If it doesn't work, create a new project and add the same `Podfile` (just change the target name). Run `pod install`.

- If it compiles fine, then your project must have been misconfigured somehow. You may want to migrate your project into that newly created one. (copy all files and add project references)
- If it does not compile, I think there is something wrong with your system.

Please try those steps and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cocoapods is the latest version.
Try to install cocoapods that lower than 1.0.

config the podfile and run pod install.